# Retrieving database associations and filling with NULL value when no association exists

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I have three Postgresql tables associateds to another table:

USER (id_user, first_name, last_name)

ADDRESS (id_address, id_user, address)

BANK_CARD (id_bank_card, id_user, number)

NETWORK (id_network, id_user, status)

A user can have multiple addresses, bank cards and networks.

For instance for USER table:

```
id_user    first_name     last_name
-------------------------------------
 1          John           Doe
 2          David          Smith
```

For ADDRESS table:

```
id_address    id_user    address
----------------------------------
 10            1          address1
```

For BANK_CARD:

```
id_bank_card    id_user     number
-----------------------------------
 20              1           1234
 21              1           5678
```

For NETWORK:

```
id_network    id_user    status
--------------------------------
 30            1          status1
 31            1          status2
 32            1          status3
```

I want to retrieve the existing associations between a user and the other tables as follows:

```
id_user  id_address  address  id_bank_card  number  id_network  status
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
 1        10         address1      20       1234       30       status1
 1        NULL       NULL          21       5678       31       status2
 1        NULL       NULL          NULL     NULL       32       status3
```

I have tried different queries using JOIN or UNION but nothing works. Thank you for helping.

Comment: Did you try to do an OUTER JOIN?

Comment: Using `JOIN` is short-hand *(and a short-hand I recommend avoiding)* for `INNER JOIN`.  This elimates rows where the join fais.  Try `LEFT JOIN` *(also known as `LEFT OUTER JOIN`)*.  This retains rows even if the join fails.  *(Also worth looking up `FULL OUTER JOIN` and `RIGHT OUTER JOIN` for additional understanding.)*

Comment: A question about your expected results: You have implicitly associated `network 30` with `card 20`, but why?  Your model doesn't actually have such a relationship.

Answer (score 1):

One approach to this uses `union all` and aggregation:

```
select id_user, max(id_address) as id_address,
       max(id_bank_card) as id_bank_card,
       max(number) as number,
       max(id_network) as id_bank_card,
       max(status) as status)
from ((select id_user, id_address, NULL as id_bank_card, NULL as number,
              NULL as id_network, NULL as status
              row_number() over (partition by id_user order by id_address) as seqnum
       from address
      ) union all
      (select id_user, NULL as id_address, id_bank_card, number,
              NULL as id_network, NULL as  status
              row_number() over (partition by id_user order by id_bank_card) as seqnum
       from bank_card
      ) union all
      (select id_user, NULL as id_address, NULL as id_bank_card, NULL as number,
              id_network, status
              row_number() over (partition by id_user order by id_network) as seqnum
       from network
      )
     ) abcn
group by id_user, seqnum;
```

You might find that putting the results in arrays is more practical:

```
select *
from (select id_user, array_agg(id_address) as id_addresses
      from address
      group by id_user
     ) a full outer join
     (select id_user, array_agg(id_bank_card) as id_bank_cards,
             array_agg(number) as numbers
      from bank_card
      group by id_user
     ) bc
     using (id_user) full outer join
     (select id_user, array_agg(id_network) as id_networds,
             array_agg(status) as statuses
      from network
      group by id_user
     ) n
     using (id_user);
```

Comment: I like the `UNION ALL` as it avoids the `COALESCE()` needed in my answer.  Would be interested to see how postgresql handles the data types when the first query contains NULL *(may need / benefit from an explicit `CAST()` around the NULLs?)*.

Comment: @MatBailie . . . A simple example suggests that it works correctly:  `select NULL as y, NULL as z union all select 'abc', 3.5`.

Answer (score 0):

`LEFT JOIN` gets you most of the way there.

The messiest bit is that you actually want joins where there is no explicit relationship, but without duplication.

The answer below introduces an additional computed field so that:
- the 1st bank card always gets assigned to the 1st address
- the 1st network   always gets assigned to the 1st bank card
- the 2nd bank card always gets assigned to the 2nd address
- the 2nd network   always gets assigned to the 2nd bank card
- etc, etc

```
WITH
    sorted_address AS
(
    SELECT
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id_user ORDER BY id_address) AS ordinal,
        *
    FROM
        address
),
    sorted_bank_card AS
(
    SELECT
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id_user ORDER BY id_bank_card) AS ordinal,
        *
    FROM
        bank_card
),
    sorted_network AS
(
    SELECT
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id_user ORDER BY id_network) AS ordinal,
        *
    FROM
        network
)
SELECT
    *
FROM
    user
LEFT JOIN
    sorted_address
        ON  sorted_address.id_user   = user.id_user
LEFT JOIN
    sorted_bank_card
        ON  sorted_bank_card.id_user = user.id_user
        AND sorted_bank_card.ordinal = sorted_address.ordinal
LEFT JOIN
    sorted_network
        ON  sorted_network.id_user   = user.id_user
        AND sorted_network.ordinal   = COALESCE(sorted_bank_card.ordinal, sorted_address.ordinal)
```

As a side note: I recommend not using reserved keywords such as `user` for table names.